# Why does this PNG show differently sometimes?

Tags: image, png

I am playing around with CodePress for a small project, and I am trying to figure out how it generates the actual numbers for the line number display.

I have looked all through the code, and I see nothing where 1, 2, 3, ..., n is outputted. However, when viewing the page info in Firefox, I see this: [alt text http://grab.by/grabs/3bce2f7860459dabcf4019862ec320a0.png](http://grab.by/grabs/3bce2f7860459dabcf4019862ec320a0.png)

Now, when I actually go to that URL in Firefox (here is the image from a CodePress example site: http://bobdawg.org/codepress/images/linenumbers.png) I just see a line with no numbers, like this:

[alt text http://grab.by/grabs/11cbd4cd7808ebccde0de59a1b0a63b5.png](http://grab.by/grabs/11cbd4cd7808ebccde0de59a1b0a63b5.png)

So how in the world are the numbers being generated? Clearly they're somehow embedded in the PNG, but how?

Comment: What a hackish way to do that

Comment: I readily agree. You can't even change the styling for the numbers. I would rather do it with two side-be-side divs. I may just modify CodePress and submit a patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image dimensions are 26x24010. What you see in Firefox is a zoomed out version of the image. If you click on it to view it at full size it will look the same as the preview.

Answer (score 4):

You need to zoom in.

Save to desktop and open with Paint.